# Use For and save and saa in diferent files

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to take 2 files from one command, in one file I only put 1 entries and the other complete a list, this is the example:

I tried various commands

```
#!/bin/bash
    for i in range 4
     do
      echo "test" >one  >>list
    done
```

I need what in the "one" save the last one loop and in the "list" everyone.

Comment: i dont know if now is more redeable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tee` for this, since tee will still write to stdout you can do something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in range 4
 do
  echo "test" | tee one >>list
done
```

or this if you want to see echos when you run it, the -a flag tells tee to append rather than truncate

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in range 4
 do
  echo "test" | tee one | tee -a list
done
```